# What is the difference between the "container" and "data" elements in SimpleModal?

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

In the SimpleModal modal dialog plugin for jQuery there are properties for a "overlay", "container" and "data". What is the difference between the container and data?

The examples demonstrate how to manipulate each of these properties, but I can not find an explanation of each.

Comment: They're all elements that go into the modal.  Create one and then use the inspector to take a look at the modal elements.

Answer (score 0):

The container is the actual graphical modal window. Data is what goes inside the container.

To put it in HTML terms:

```
<div id="simplemodal-container">
    <div id="simplemodal-data">
        *your contents go here*
    </div>
</div>
```